# Any established convenient callback writing styles for javascript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax, coding-style, callback

Callbacks are more and more a requirement in coding, especially when you think about `Node.JS` non-blocking style of working. But writing a lot of *coroutine callbacks* quickly becomes difficult to read back.

For example, imagine something like this [Pyramid Of Doom](http://calculist.org/blog/2011/12/14/why-coroutines-wont-work-on-the-web/):

```
// This asynchronous coding style is really annoying. Anyone invented a better way yet?
// Count, remove, re-count (verify) and log.
col.count(quertFilter,          function(err, countFiltered) {
    col.count(queryCached,      function(err, countCached) {
        col.remove(query,       function(err) {
            col.count(queryAll, function(err, countTotal) {
                util.log(util.format('MongoDB cleanup: %d filtered and %d cached records removed. %d last-minute records left.', countFiltered, countCached, countTotal));
            });
        });
    });
});
```

is something we see often and can easily become more complex.

When every function is at least a couple of lines longer, it starts to become feasible to separate the functions:

```
// Imagine something more complex

function mary(data, pictures) {
    // Do something drastic
}

// I want to do mary(), but I need to write how before actually starting.

function nana(callback, cbFinal) {
    // Get stuff from database or something
    callback(nene, cbFinal, data);
}

function nene(callback, cbFinal, data) {
    // Do stuff with data
    callback(nini, cbFinal, data);
}

function nini(callback, data) {
    // Look up pictures of Jeff Atwood
    callback(data, pictures);
}

// I start here, so this story doesn't read like a book even if it's quite straightforward.

nana(nene, mary);
```

But there is a lot of passing vars around happening all the time. With other functions written in between, this becomes hard to read. The functions itself might be too insignificant on their own to justify giving them their own file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A different approach to callbacks are promises.

Example: jQuery Ajax. this one might look pretty familiar.

```
$.ajax({
  url: '/foo',
  success: function() {
      alert('bar');
  }  
});
```

But $.ajax also returns a promise.

```
var request = $.ajax({
  url: '/foo'
});

request.done(function() {
    alert('bar');
});
```

A benefit is, that you simulate synchronous behavior, because you can use the returned promise instead of providing a callback to $.ajax.success and a callback to the callback and a callback.... Another advantage is, that you can chain / aggregate promises, and have error handlers for one promise-aggregate if you like.

I found [this article](http://sporto.github.com/blog/2012/12/09/callbacks-listeners-promises/) to be pretty useful.
It describes the pro and cons of callbacks, promises and other techniques.

A popular implementation (used by e.g. AngularJS iirc) is [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q).

Comment: Thank you, this is valuable. Those promises look (sorry) promising. I am looking for a 'sec' way to apply this to `Node.JS` or plain javascript directly. I will upvote your answer for now but wait for more answers before I accept one. :)

Comment: `Q` sounds promising, but the docs on `Github` are confusing. They mean well, but they fail to explain basics like what needs to go where in order to actually use this. [Here](http://howtonode.org/promises) is a nice overview and you probably recognize the constructs, but still, for someone who is new to this technique, there's no simple list of facts like what goes where, what is returned where, how are errors thrown, were are callbacks specified, etc. I consider myself quite the tech-savvy person, but do you happen to know any resource for even more clueless people?

Comment: Could you provide an example in your answer how to do the above Pyramid of Doom in Q?

Answer (score 6):

Use an async flow control library like [`async`](https://github.com/caolan/async).  It provides a clean way to structure code that requires multiple async calls while maintaining whatever dependency is present between them (if any).

In your example, you'd do something like this:

```
async.series([
    function(callback) { col.count(queryFilter, callback); },
    function(callback) { col.count(queryCached, callback); },
    function(callback) { col.remove(query, callback); },
    function(callback) { col.count(queryAll, callback); }
], function (err, results) {
    if (!err) {
        util.log(util.format('MongoDB cleanup: %d filtered and %d cached records removed. %d last-minute records left.', 
            results[0], results[1], results[3]));
    }  
});
```

This would execute each of the functions in series; once the first one calls its callback the second one is invoked, and so on.  But you can also use `parallel` or `waterfall` or whatever flow matches the flow you're looking for.  I find it's much cleaner than using promises.

Comment: If I do the same with the more versatile `async.waterfall()` method `function(err, queryFilter, cb) { col.count(queryCached, cb); tools.log('teststep 2'); }` it doesn't go past step 2. Any chance you can add the `waterfall()` variant to your answer?

Comment: @Redsandro Omit the `err` parameter to your function. However, `waterfall` doesn't seem like a good fit for your example as you need all previous results available to the `util.log` call and not just the result from the last function in the chain.

Comment: I see, thanks. I think waterfall is more versatile because you can pass as many functions to the callback as you want (although in this case just one) as long as you specify them: `function(these, vars, will, be, available, callback) \\ in util.log`

Answer (score 2):

Combined answers and articles. Please edit this answer and add libraries/examples/doc-urls in a straightforward fasion for everyone's benefit.

**Documentation on Promises**

- [Asynchronous Control Flow with Promises](http://howtonode.org/promises)
- [jQuery deferreds](http://sitr.us/2012/07/31/promise-pipelines-in-javascript.html)

**Asynchronous Libraries**

- [async.js](https://github.com/caolan/async)

  ```
  async.waterfall([
      function(){ // ... },
      function(){ // ... }
  ], callback);
  ```
- [node fibers](https://npmjs.org/package/fibers)
- [step](https://github.com/creationix/step)

  ```
  Step(
      function func1() {
          // ...
          return value
      },
      function func2(err, value) {
          // ...
          return value
      },
      function funcFinal(err, value) {
          if (err) throw err;
      // ...
      }
  );
  ```
- [Q](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/)

  ```
  Q.fcall(func1)
      .then(func2)
      .then(func3)
      .then(funcSucces, funcError)
  ```

  - [API reference](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/API-Reference)
  - [Mode examples](https://github.com/kriskowal/q/wiki/Examples-Gallery)
  - [More documentation](https://npmjs.org/package/q)