# IndexedDB: avoiding callback-hell

Tags: javascript, html, indexeddb, asynccallback

I have an IndexedDB which is locally caching data with three properties a,b and c. a and b together form a composite key and c is the content I'm after.

Now, the client gets from the server a list of items which I want to display. Then the client should look up (a,b) in the IndexedDB and retrieve the matching c, then hash c using sha1 (using Rusha, this already works fine).

For those items, where the sha1(c_client) does not match sha1(c_server), the client retrieves all (a,b) pairs from the server (using one GET request with a JSON-serialized array of (a,b)). The server returns the updated content of c, and then the client stores the new c in the IndexedDB and then gives the whole array of objects to the display function.

As you can see, the most part of the logic absolutely needs sequential operations - but IndexedDB is highly asynchronous.

Any way to do what I want in a synchronous way?

Comment: Until the major browsers implement ES6 generators there is no way to "just write synchronously". Your best bet is using a [control-flow library](https://github.com/fjakobs/async.js) to ease the pain or program in  an async-aware superset of Javascript that compiles into the callback version of the code, like [this](http://facebook.github.io/regenerator/)

Comment: Basically this would require me wrapping the whole IndexedDB API into an async.js-wrapper?

Comment: No, your code will still interact with the indexdBAPI via the same callbacks as before. The difference is that those tools let your code be a bit more organized instead of having that ["pyramid of doom"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14257696/any-established-convenient-callback-writing-styles-for-javascript) pattern of nested callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

My approach to the `IndexedDB` callbacks was with event dispatching, using the [publish subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). You can code your own handler or use JQuery triggers.

What I've done is grouped all logical `IndexedDB` events and when the `IndexedDB` callback happens it would notify the publisher that what kind of event occurred and publisher will notify all the functions that are waiting for that event.

Example events that I have are: 
database created, indexing completed, synchronization started, synchronization completed...
I also have events for synchronization progress which are used to notify the user of the progress (I'm syncing in batches).

Publish-subscribe model allowed me high level of decoupling of the `IndexedDB` code with the UI code and thus allowing me to easily modify the event actions code or add more listeners to same event. If you need sequential function you can chain the events, when one finishes to trigger that it's done and the next one can continue.

Comment: Pubsub pattern is too decoupled,  will lead to spreattigi code. Promise or generator* pattern are preferable for indexed db api.

Comment: Hi Kyaw I agree that the promise pattern is better approach for event chaining, however in my case it works good with the pubsub pattern, since I use for connecting different logical entities and I don't have deep chaining.

Answer (score 0):

The sync version of the IndexedDB API was abandoned before the spec was finalized so you'll always have to work in an asynchronous manner.

I was also annoyed by the API so I created a simple wrapper called [db.js](http://github.com/aaronpowell/db.js) which uses Promises for the querying. If you're lucky enough to be only targeting a platform that supports generators you can combine them with db.js to [make it more synchronous](http://www.aaron-powell.com/posts/2014-01-28-cleaning-up-promises-wit-yield.html).